# How can I get autocomplete to work for IntelliJ Ruby plugin?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, jruby

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.4 with the latest version of the Ruby plugin and JRuby 1.6.0. Autocomplete doesn't seem to work. Pressing ctrl-space only shows me a few top level things.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
```

If I type M and ctrl-space I would expect to see Mechanize in the list but I get nothing. If I ctrl-space on an empty line I get a few top level things (**FILE**, **LINE**, alias, begin...).

Comment: My script does run BTW so Mechanize et al are installed

Comment: I downloaded RubyMine and that works so its not my JRuby installation

Comment: Update IDEA and use the most recent version of the Ruby plug-in which is more close to RubyMine version than the old version you have with IDEA 9.0.4.

Comment: Also make sure you set your project's SDK as Ruby, and make sure IDEA is configured with the correct Ruby path.